# ibm_boto3 compatibility issue with scikit-learn on Mac OS

Tags: python, scikit-learn, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I have a Python 3.6 application that uses [`scikit-learn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/), deployed to IBM Cloud (Cloud Foundry). It works fine. My local development environment is Mac OS High Sierra.

Recently, I added IBM Cloud Object Storage functionality ([`ibm_boto3`](https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-python)) to the app. The COS functionality itself works fine. I'm able to upload, download, list, and delete objects just fine using the `ibm_boto3` library.

Strangely, the part of the app that uses `scikit-learn` now freezes up.

If I comment out the ibm_boto3 `import` statements (and corresponding code), the `scikit-learn` code works fine.

More perplexingly, the issue only happens on the local development machine running OS X. When the app is deployed to IBM Cloud, it works fine -- both `scikit-learn` and `ibm_boto3` work well side-by-side.

Our only hypothesis at this point is that somehow the `ibm_boto3` library surfaces a known issue in `scikit-learn` (see [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means) -- parallel version of the K-means algorithm is broken when `numpy` uses Accelerator on OS X). 
Note that we only face this issue once we add `ibm_boto3` to the project.

However, we need to be able to test on localhost before deploying to IBM Cloud. Are there any known compatibility issues between `ibm_boto3` and `scikit-learn` on Mac OS?

Any suggestions on how we can avoid this on the dev machine?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up until now, there weren't any known compatibility issues. :)

At some point there were some issues with the vanilla SSL libraries that come with OSX, but if you're able to read and write data that isn't the problem.

Are you using [HMAC credentials](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/iam/service-credentials.html#service-credentials)?  If so, I'm curious if the behavior continues if you use the original `boto3` library instead of the IBM fork.

Here's a simple examples that shows how you might use `pandas` with the original `boto3`:

```
import boto3  # package used to connect to IBM COS using the S3 API
import io  # python package used to stream data
import pandas as pd  # lightweight data analysis package

access_key = '<access key>'
secret_key = '<secret key>'
pub_endpoint = 'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net'
pvt_endpoint = 'https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.service.networklayer.com'
bucket = 'demo'  # the bucket holding the objects being worked on.
object_key = 'demo-data'  # the name of the data object being analyzed.
result_key = 'demo-data-results'  # the name of the output data object.


# First, we need to open a session and create a client that can connect to IBM COS.
# This client needs to know where to connect, the credentials to use,
# and what signature protocol to use for authentication. The endpoint
# can be specified to be public or private.
cos = boto3.client('s3', endpoint_url=pub_endpoint,
                   aws_access_key_id=access_key,
                   aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
                   region_name='us',
                   config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

# Since we've already uploaded the dataset to be worked on into cloud storage,
# now we just need to identify which object we want to use. This creates a JSON
# representation of request's response headers.
obj = cos.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=object_key)

# Now, because this is all REST API based, the actual contents of the file are
# transported in the request body, so we need to identify where to find the
# data stream containing the actual CSV file we want to analyze.
data = obj['Body'].read()

# Now we can read that data stream into a pandas dataframe.
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data))

# This is just a trivial example, but we'll take that dataframe and just
# create a JSON document that contains the mean values for each column.
output = df.mean(axis=0, numeric_only=True).to_json()

# Now we can write that JSON file to COS as a new object in the same bucket.
cos.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=result_key, Body=output)
```

Comment: Agreed -- I imagine this is an edge case, and thank you for looking into it. No, we're not using HMAC credentials. Could you point me to an example that uses HMAC credentials with the original `boto3` library? I'll be happy to give that a try and report what I find.

Comment: Thanks... I'll try this in combination with the `scikit-learn` library and share what I find. As an aside, does this mean the `boto3` library works out of the box with IBM COS? Is that a supported / recommended way of connecting to IBM COS? I imagine there are specific provider-level differences that `ibm_boto3` addresses, just not sure what they are.

Comment: While troubleshooting this issue, I commented out all the `ibm_boto3` code I was using, and then added it back line-by-line. I was able to isolate it to a `requests.get()` call to get the COS endpoints. I have no explanation for why this breaks `scikit-learn`, and only on MacOS. I do not think this has anything to do with `ibm_boto3` at all. It must be a bug with `scikit-learn`.

I'll accept the answer so we can close out the question.

Thank you much for your help!

Comment: Happy to help, and glad you got it working.

Yes, COS is _mostly_ compatible with the S3 API, so pretty much any tool that can talk to AWS S3 can also talk to COS.  The key deltas between the IBM fork and the original library is support for creating a client using an API key and Service Instance ID instead of Access/Secret keys, support for a custom IAM token manager, and some IBM specific APIs for creating buckets where encryption is managed using Key Protect.  Soon there will be additional support for using Aspera for file transfers and some other goodies.